# Get the list of selected cells in different sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

The user can select/deselect cells in each section, so to track all the selected cells in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not useful:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"row = %i, section = %i", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
}
```

What i want instead is to save time and resources, so to let the user check/uncheck whatever he wants, and when he **click on a button** (to go to next view), i need to collect all selected cells in the whole table view. I tried to do like this:

```
-(IBAction)nextView:(id)sender{

themesChoosed=[self.tView indexPathsForSelectedRows];//tView is the outlet of my UITableView and themesChosed is an NSArray declared in the .h file
    for (int i=0; i<=[themesChoosed count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *thisPath = [themesChoosed objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"row = %i, section = %i", thisPath.row, thisPath.section);

}
}
```

But this doesn't return me the selected cells, it shows me always: `row = 0, section = 0` as if i am only selecting the first cell in the first section.
Any thoughts on how to do so?

Comment: how many sections you are displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *selectedArray;
```

in .m

```
viewDidLoad

 selectedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

in tableviewDidSelect

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//According to section take value from table and get string selectedString.

if([selectedArray containsObject:selectedString])

{
[selectedArray removeObject:selectedString];

}

else

{
[selectedArray addObject:selectedString];

}

}
```